# Prototype function to set onclick event observer in checkboxes

Tags: events, checkbox, click, prototypejs

I want to set an observer for each of the following checkboxes:

```
<div id="listr">
  <ul id="lr" style="list-style-type: none">
    <p class="tir">Text 1</p>
    <li class="ro"><input type="checkbox" name="r1" id="r1"/>A1</li>
    <li class="ro"><input type="checkbox" name="r2" />A2</li>
    <p class="tir">Text 2</p>
    <li class="rubro"><input type="checkbox" name="r3" />B1</li>
    <p class="tir">Text 3</p>
    <li class="ro"><input type="checkbox" name="r4" />B2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It works if I write one observer per checkbox, but I want to do it in a short fashion, so I need something like

```
$$('listr.lr.li.input').invoke('observe',click,function(field) {
    alert(this.name + ' clicked ' + this.checked);
    // other stuff ...
});
```

Which is not working

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a valid [CSS3 selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#selectors):

```
$$('#listr input[type="checkbox"]').invoke('observe','click',function(field) {
    alert(this.name + ' clicked ' + this.checked);
    // other stuff ...
});
```

http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/dollar-dollar/

Comment: This is little, but I think you meant to add quotes around `click` in the arguments to `invoke()`.